# Recalculating mean and std avg (Python, Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

The problem: I need to recalculate mean and std dev for last n minutes *every minute*.

That is, if we assume `n == 3`, then I have 3 data frames for say minutes 12:01, 12:02, 12:03. At 12:04 calculate mean, std dev for those last 3 minutes.

At 12:05 I need to recalculate mean and std dev of dataframes for 12:02, 12:03, 12:04.

Now I can `concat` the last 3 dataframes on a new minute passing and then calculate what I need. But that means I'm needlessly recalculating every dataframe `n-1` times.

Is there a way of "suspending" computation on dataframes or saving the intermediate results, adding a dataframe and then resuming it? (cpt Obvious plugin: for mathematical reasons I can't just average the last `n-1` means and std dev values -- theoretically I could average the means if a number of samples in every df were equal, but it's not)

(Obviously, I do not have entire past dataset available at once - every minute 1 new df is incoming and the df number older than `n` minutes is "deleted" from calculation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate `Mean (M), Second Moment (M2) and Std (D)` for each dataframe and when you need to aggregate some of them you can use the properties of this statistics:

> m_i = len(X_i)
>
> M(X_i) = sum(x for x in X_i) / m_i
>
> M2(X_i) = sum(x ** 2 for x in X_i) / m_i
>
> M(X1,X2,...Xn) = sum(M(X_i) * m_i) / sum(m_i)
>
> M2(X1,X2,...Xn) = sum(M2(X_i) * m_i ) / sum(m_i)
>
> D(X1, X2,...Xn) = M2(X1,X2,...Xn) - M(X1,X2,...Xn) ** 2
>
> Then Std = sqrt(D)
>
> where m_i - number of observations in X_i sample

for more information see [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_%28mathematics%29)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
rolling = numpy.zeros(n)
for i, minute_df in enumerate(new_df):
  rolling[i % n] = minute_df.mean()
  print rolling.mean()
```